# My apk file doesn't work on the mobile

Tags: xamarin

I had create a program using Xamarin but when i convert it to apk file the apk instilled on the mobile but doesn't run. whenever i try to run it a message appears which told me that the process had been stoped

Comment: Which build configuration have you used? Do you deploy directly on your device or do you copy the apk and give it away?

Answer (score 0):

Create Android Apk with Xamarin.

1 - Change configurations "Debug" to "Release"

2 - Now go to tab "Project" and click "Create Android Package"

3 - Choose destination folder

4 - Copy the .apk on your phone, install and run application

Comment: So Debug releases wont run on a device?

Comment: Surely he copy the apk on another phone where there is not the installed monoandroid_platform

Comment: Xamarin/Visual studio will not build an APK unless it's a release build. @CathalMF

Answer (score 0):

The process to build an APK has changed in Visual Studio 2017.

Right click on the Android project and select 'Archive...'
Then sign the apk through the distribute button.

Now it should install on devices in developer mode.