# Build option for Xamarin studio is not completely comming

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to generate an apk from xamarin Studio but some Android options under Build are not coming.

This is the screenshot of my project solution
[Build option is marked but some Android options are not coming which are required to generate apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTrTX.png)

Xamarin Studio
Version 5.9.7(build 22)

[This screenshot shows actually what should come under the build option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J7ln.png)

I am currently developing a project and I am currently facing a big problem as I cannot generate apk in xamarin studio as some options are not coming.

Please friends help me out.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526238/my-apk-file-doesnt-work-on-the-mobile/33527179#33527179

Answer (score 2):

You selected your solution, not your project. If you select the project instead you will have other options.